# Does java provides html/jsp extending method just like python and C#mvc?

Tags: java, html, model-view-controller

I am in learning java spring boot. Before java,  I created my websites using python flask or C# MVC.
It was quite different between java and python. I was wondering, does java provide a way to extend the HTML page that I can create some generic templates just like python and C#?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with asp.net Mvc Razor view engine long time ago but from what I can remember you can do everything you have been doing with Razor view with jsp.  their approach are different but you can do thing somehow the same way. Also there are some other template engines like `Thymeleaf`that are based on jsp but have extended that to the reacher point which you can use. By the way to my mind frameworks like `JSF` and `Primefaces` in java are much more similar to Razor view engine in asp.Net Mvc.